# swift dynamic list with multiple labels per row that can be selected, highlighted and capture the value

Tags: swift, xcode

I’ve developed a survey that allows users to enter five questions with a response selection from 1 to 5.  My current version has five labels for the questions and five buttons for the response values.  The labels and number values are pulled from a database.  When the form is submitted I pass the question and selected response value back to the database.   I’m trying to figure out how to create a dynamic survey that is not limited on the number of questions.

In testing I did develop a survey using a table view and custom cell.  In the cell I had five labels, one for the question and the rest were response selection labels.  The problem I had was trying to select an individual label for each question and highlighting the selected response.

Is it possible to create a dynamic list with multiple labels per row that can be selected, highlighted and capture the value?  I’m new to XCODE and swift so I may be going about this the wrong way.

[My current survey image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsK8c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your labels to buttons, you can capture the value when the button is pressed and store it in an array corresponding to its row number.

```
var answers: [String] = []

@IBAction func ratingButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as! UIButton // This is the rating button that was pressed inside the cell
    let currentCell = button.superview!.superview!.superview! as! MatchupCell // This gets the cell that has that pressed button
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(currentCell)
    currentRow = (indexPath?.row)! // This gets the row of the cell

    answers[currentRow] = button.titleLabel!.text! // Store the pressed value in the array at the index that matches the row number
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a fast and helpful response, this is perfect.  In order to get my buttons to respond with clicked I had to right click the buttons, select “Touch Up Inside” and drag that to the View Controller and select the function.

Comment: @Nathern Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you